# How to set gauge in FeynCalc?

Tags: feyncalc

I want to set gauge in all of my calculation with FeynArts and FeynCalc to $\xi$ gauge.

I use `$Gauge=ξ` but it does not work.

How to change gauge in these packages?

Thanks.

Comment: FeynArts manual, p. 43 option GaugeRules. I highly recommend reading the manual completely before using FeynArts. This avoids a lot of questions.

Comment: @vsht Thanks for your answer and suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
diags = InsertFields[
   CreateTopologies[1, 1 -> 2], {F[4, {3}]} -> {S[1], F[4, {2}]},
   InsertionLevel -> {Classes}, Model -> "SM"];

CreateFeynAmp[diags, PreFactor -> 1/(2 Pi)^4, GaugeRules -> {}]
```

This provides amplitudes in general $R_\xi$ gauge